# AppBar Layout Expands Automatically when View visibility is changed from Gone to Visible on runtime

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

As we can see from the below sample, on changing the visibility of the view from gone to visible and vice versa, the appbar automatically expands and scrim drawn is shown as well.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/crl_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@drawable/shape_rectangle_grdient_red_yellow"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fl_class"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/d_280dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPlaceholderBg">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_class"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@color/colorPlaceholderBg" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/pb_dp_progress"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/d_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/d_20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_default_height"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_transparent_grey_gradient">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
                        ... />




            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tl_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_default_height"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/d_0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_class_details_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This the code for the outer layout. As can be seen from the above layout that the pattern is mostly standard. I have tried replicating the bug in new sample but of no use. The initial problem seem to be changing the height of nested scroll view on runtime seems to be the problem but that is not the case. I tried to setExpand(false) on the click of the button but that is not working as well.

```html
<a href="https://imgur.com/YGTT3oL"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/YGTT3oL.gif" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>
```

Link to demo gif is here: https://i.imgur.com/YGTT3oL.gif

Comment: Did you try using setExpanded(true/false) when you are doing hide/show?

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is caused by app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"

You have to define the behavior you want when scrolling, check out this article: https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-collapsing-toolbar-scrollflags-e1d8a05dcb02

Since I dont know what behaviour do you want, read the article and choose yourself. Hiding and showing the view is triggering those flags.

Answer (score 0):

In your **@layout/fragment_class_details_content** check if

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

is present in the parent layout.

Also change  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap" to

> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

Add this attribute to the CollapsingToolbarLayout

> app:toolbarId="@+id/tl_toolbar"

Add this attribute to Toolbar:

> app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

Answer (score -2):

Extract your gone/visible layout from `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Too much nesting you did so avoid nesting and Use constraint layout

Comment: - Nesting is not the issue here because I tried the same scenario with reduced nesting but the problem still persists.
- Extracting the visibility and setting it explicitly on AppBarLayout is not solving my problem as well.